# How to find the numbers of unique words in a list

Tags: python, list

For example:

```
["apple", "banana", "apple", "mango"]
```

Comment: What defines "combining" here?

Comment: Word[0] = example[0]; Word[1] = example[1]+ example[2]; Word[2] = example[3]+ example[4] +example[5]+ example[6] + example[7];...i think this can be done for only ["I","a","m","h","a","p","p","y"] To become ["I","am","happy"]

Comment: How do you know where in the list the words should split properly?

Comment: To answer your updated question: `words = ["apple", "banana", "apple", "mango"]` `len(set(words))`

Answer (score 4):

The string "join" method may be useful for you here, but it won't give you that answer that you appear to desire. To join elements of a list with "nothing":

```
In [1]: "".join(["I","a","m","h","a","p","p","y"])
Out[1]: 'Iamhappy'
```

if your list included spaces, you could have done:

```
In [2]: "".join(["I"," ","a","m"," ","h","a","p","p","y"])
Out[2]: 'I am happy'
```

followed by a string "split" on the spaces:

```
In [3]: 'I am happy'.split(" ")
Out[3]: ['I', 'am', 'happy']
```

But to parse the original result (Out[1]) for dictionary words is another matter.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a definition for how to combine the elements in the list?

So, suppose for your example you had

```
x = ["I","a","m","h","a","p","p","y"]
comb = [1, 2, 5]
```

Then

```
def combine(l, comb):
    x = []

    if sum(comb) == len(l):
        for n, i in enumerate(comb):
            d = sum(comb[:n])
            x.append(''.join(l[d : d + i]))
        return x
    return l
```

and `combine(x, comb)` will return `['I', 'am', 'happy']`.